# Решение системы нелинейных уравнений в MATLAB

Tags: matlab

Имеется система уравнений:

```
x-5+sin(x+y+z-5)/2=0
y-sin(x+y+z-5)/10=0
z+sin(x+y+z-5)/12=0
```

Не могу понять, как найти решение именно в MATLAB. Во-первых необходимо найти начальные приближения с помощью построения графиков. Как построить графики этих уравнений? И имеются ли в MATLAB простые методы решения СНУ, либо необходимо реализовывать собственные алгоритмы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сложив ур-ния, получим:

```
x + y + z - 5 + 29/60 * sin(x + y + z - 5) = 0;
w = x + y + z - 5;
w + 29/60*sin(w) = 0;
```

это ур-ние решаем по Ньютону и, в конце концов, находим sin(w).
А дальше, вычисляем неизвестные из каждого начального ур-ния

Comment: Нет ли там ошибки? Получается x=5, z = y = 0; Слишком тривиально :-((

Comment: Может быть, там косинус, а не синус?

Comment: В принципе, для решения системы вашего ответа вполне достаточно. Но мне все равно нужно найти начальные приближения с помощью графиков (для ручного просчета собственных алгоритмов).

Comment: "...начальные приближения с помощью графиков...". Какие же начальные приближения тут могут быть, уважаемый @VadimBorovin, если синусоида встречается с этой прямой только в одной точке: (0;0)?